# C# The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, momentjs

I Apologies now, but I'm not great with dates.

I'm passing a date parameter into a MVC Controller(ASP.net)
however sometimes (its happned twice) it does not like a particular time of the day and throws the following error:

Exception: mscorlib The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

I've had this on the two following values:

Query: dateTime=13%2f03%2f2017+13%3a08

Query: dateTime=12%2f03%2f2017+21%3a07

Using Moment to try and format

```
function addNewMeeting(date) {

    var currentDate = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY%20HH:mm").toString();

    $("#appEventPlaceholder").load("/Meeting/AddEvent?dateTime=" + currentDate,
        function () {
            $('#eventModal').modal('show');
        }
        );
};

 public ActionResult AddEvent(string date = null, string resourceId = null)
        {
..}
```

I guess i'm doing something wrong with formatting the date? Could someone show me what I should be doing please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you leave out the time? (remove %20HH:mm) - this will help narrow down the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
try this Convert.toDateTime(string)
```